# How can I tell Rails 6 and webpack to use only particular css and js on a layout

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, webpack

I am working on a simple rails project.

Under app->javascript->dashboard I have two js files:

- metisMenu.min.js
- startmin.js

I included them on my application.js file under app->javascript->packs:

```
require("turbolinks").start()
require("@rails/activestorage")
require("channels")


require("dashboard/metisMenu.min")
require("dashboard/startmin")


import 'bootstrap'
import './stylesheets/application.scss'
```

For my CSS files I have a stylesheets folder under app->javascript->packs where I have also these:

- metisMenu.min.scss
- startmin.scss
- _custom.scss

Where in my application.scss folder I included them:

```
$$fa-font-path: '~@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/webfonts';
@import "~@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/fontawesome";
@import "~@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/solid";
@import "~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";
@import "metisMenu.min";
@import "startmin";
```

Finally, I have two layouts under views->layouts:

- dashboard.html.erb
- application.html.erb

Now my question is how do I force rails 6 and webpack to use only specific CSS and JS files for a specific layout. For instance under dashboard.html.erb, I only want to use these JS files:

- metisMenu.min.js
- startmin.js

And then on my CSS I only want to use these:
 - metisMenu.min.scss
 - startmin.scss

Along with the regular bootstrp and jQuery. How can I do these?

Answer (score 1):

Use different packers.
You decide, in your layout file, which pack to use:

This should look like this for ERB:

```
<%= javascript_pack_tag 'application' %>
```

or for HAML:

```
= javascript_pack_tag 'application'
```

Since it's in the layout file, you can decide to use a different file than the standard `application.js`.

A good approach would be to have a shared pack file (with your libraries, for example) and then one with the per-layout javascript:

```
<!-- dashboard.html.erb -->
<%= javascript_pack_tag 'libs' %>
<%= javascript_pack_tag 'dashboard' %>
<!-- application.html.erb -->
<%= javascript_pack_tag 'libs' %>
<%= javascript_pack_tag 'application' %>
```